# Выдает ошибку при старте npm serve

Tags: vue.js, npm

ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                                                                                                                11:03:33

This relative module was not found:

- ./src/main.js in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://10.98.220.68:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js, multi (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://10.98.220.68:8080/sockjs-node ./src/main.js

Comment: Какая структура проекта? Как проект создавался? Какой версией cli, если она использовалась. Непонятно. Много неясно в вопросе.

Comment: Вообщем проблема решена, в папке проекта создал папку src а в ней main.js, все работает!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем проблема решена, в папке проекта создал папку src а в ней main.js, все работает!